# Argument type matches this class

Tags: c#, types

Consider the following:

```
public interface ITree<X>
{
  ...
  ITree<X> Union(ITree<X> other);
  ...
}
```

The idea is that I'm going to implement several types of tree. However, the `Union()` method only works if you try to union two trees of *the same type*. The type signature above does not enforce this restriction, however.

So, my question is: How can I write a type signature for `Union()` such that the `other` argument must have *the same type* as `this`?

(Obviously I can do a dynamic run-time test and throw an exception if the types don't match. But I would much, much rather to check this at compile-time if it can be done...)

Comment: @JLRishe - It won't be enforced since you could union a `RedBlackTree<X>` with a `SplayTree<X>` if they both implement `ITree<X>`.

Comment: Blast! You're right. I thought the question was referring to the `X`.

Comment: @Lee I'm not sure that's a type constraint the generics system can express in any useful way. (Over just not having the methods in the interface.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a particularly clean way of expressing this, this is a consequence of using interfaces, since there's no way to know the implementing type of `ITree<X>`. The best method is probably to create another class/interface which constrains the concrete tree type and does the operation(s) you require:

```
public interface ITreeUnion<T, X> where T : ITree<X>
{
    T Union(T left, T right);
}
```

you'll then have to pass instances of this interface type to where you need to carry out the required operation.

If you really require `Union` to go on the interface you can use a recurring template:

```
public interface ITree<T, X> where T : ITree<T, X>
{
    T Union(T other);
}

public class RedBlackTree<T> : ITree<RedBlackTree<T>, T>
{
    public RedBlackTree<T> Union(RedBlackTree<T> other)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I had tried writing terms such as `T<X>`, but the compiler didn't like it. I hadn't thought of trying to use a `T : ITree<X>` constraint; that's quite ingenious!

Comment: Related to this, you can apparently make `Union` an "extension method" to make it look much less weird. (Although this by itself doesn't give the dynamic binding I wanted.)

Answer (score 1):

According to your requirment, you would need a generic declaration of `Union()`.

- interface

  ```
  public partial interface ITree<X> {
      T Union<T>(T other) where T: ITree<X>;
  }
  ```
- sample classes

  ```
  public partial class TreeOfObject: ITree<object> {
      public T Union<T>(T other) where T: ITree<object> {
          return default(T); // sample only; shuold be implemented yourself
      }
  }

  public partial class TreeOfInt: ITree<int> {
      public T Union<T>(T other) where T: ITree<int> {
          return default(T); // sample only; shuold be implemented yourself
      }
  }
  ```
- test

  ```
  public static partial class TestClass {
      public static void TestMethod() {
          var x=new TreeOfObject();
          var y=new TreeOfInt();

          var xx=x.Union(x);
          var yy=y.Union(y);

          var xy=x.Union(y); // won't compile
          var yx=y.Union(x); // won't compile
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Ooo, that's interesting... I didn't know overrides of a method could add new type constraints to a generic parameter.

Comment: You are not overriding a method but implementing the interface. A generic method definition is regardless where the type it is defined, compiler even warn you if you declared with a same type parameter as the class definition.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the interface then? Simply implement a `Replace` method on each implementation of a tree:

```
public class RedBlackTree<T> {
    public RedBlackTree<T> Union(RedBlackTree<T> other) { ... }
}

public class SplayTree<T> {
    public SplayTree<T> Union(SplayTree<T> other) { ... }
}
```

Since you're looking for compile-time safety when dealing with each implementation of `ITree`, I would argue you just need to deal with the concrete types. Of course, you could have an `ITree<T>` with other methods on it if you require.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, the following [actually compiles](http://ideone.com/xOiLLr):

```
public interface ITree<TSelf, TItem> where TSelf : ITree<TSelf, TItem>
{
    TSelf Union(TSelf other);
    // ...
}

public class AvlTree<TItem> : ITree<AvlTree<TItem>, TItem> {
    public AvlTree<TItem> Union(AvlTree<TItem> other) {
        return other;
    }
}
```

Of course it's not particularly useful, since then you'd have to declare variables as `ITree<AvlTree>`, at which point you might as well not use the interface. With C# generics, the values of generic type parameters have to be known at some point to reify the generic type.